# Looking for Mid-Holocene (~6000 BP) bioclim dataset

Tags: raster, data

I am trying to obtain climate data for the Mid-Holocene (~6000 BP), preferably in the bioclim (19 bioclimatic variables) raster format. The worldclim.org website lists this dataset based on the CCSM and MIROC models, but does not provide any links to download the datasets. I have contacted the authors of the website and received no response. However, this dataset has been used in  Chan et al. (2011) and the lead author on the paper only responds the they obtained the data from MVZ-GIS (UC Berkeley Museum of Vertebrate Zoology GIS). I cannot find the dataset there either. Can anybody direct me to a web source for this dataset or does anybody have these data and is willing to share it? I realize that the raw data is available on the PMIPII website, but I currently do not have the skills to programmatically process this dataset into the bioclim format.

Chan et al. 2011. Integrating statistical genetic and geospatial methods brings new power to phylogeography. MPE 59 (2): 523-537 (http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1055790311000480).

Answer (score 1):

The WorldClim site links to "Paleoclimate Modelling Intercomparison Project Phase II (PMIP2) for these data. This seems to be a relevant page: http://pmip2.lsce.ipsl.fr/database/access/opendap.shtml

The data are delivered in NetCDF format.